# Driver not specified for this database connection

Tags: database

I want to connect to external database:

```
$old_database = array (
        'default' =>    array (
                'database' => 'grantexpert_registration',
                'username' => 'grantexpert_usr',
                'password' => 'xxxxxx',
                'host' => '62.168.127.59',
                'port' => '5432',
                'driver' => 'pgsql',
                'prefix' => '',
        ),
);

Database::addConnectionInfo('olddatabase', 'default', $old_database);
db_set_active('olddatabase');
```

But Im getting an error:

> Driver not specified for this database connection: olddatabase in Database::openConnection()

All the examples show exactly this structure of array, but it's not working. Is smoething wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already provided the target DB name with the second param to `addConnectionInfo()`, so you just need to remove the 'default' element from the array, and shift the connection params up:

```
$old_database = array (
  'database' => 'grantexpert_registration',
  'username' => 'grantexpert_usr',
  'password' => 'xxxxxx',
  'host' => '62.168.127.59',
  'port' => '5432',
  'driver' => 'pgsql',
  'prefix' => '',
);

Database::addConnectionInfo('olddatabase', 'default', $old_database);
db_set_active('olddatabase');
```